# inverse a List view inside a drawer

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I want to know how to make a list view inside a drawer shows from the other side, and I'm confused why it gave me the default apperance like this:

```
drawer: Drawer(
            child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                trailing: FlatButton.icon(
                    onPressed: _onClicked,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                    label: Text('Home')),
              ),
              ListTile(
                trailing: FlatButton.icon(
                    onPressed: _onClicked,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                    label: Text('Favorite')),
              ),
              ListTile(
                trailing: FlatButton.icon(
                    onPressed: _onClicked,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                    label: Text('Share_app')),
              ),
              ListTile(
                trailing: FlatButton.icon(
                    onPressed: _onClicked,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.info),
                    label: Text('About Us')),
              ),
              ListTile(
                trailing: FlatButton.icon(
                    onPressed: _onClicked,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                    label: Text('Settings')),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )));
  }
}
```

[image]

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you want to put your Icon in the `trailing` position, and also put a label to it? If you want to simply display a `ListView` of `ListTile` children, you can simply do this:

```dart
ListView(
  children: [
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.home),
      title: Text('Home'),
      onTap: // onTap callback
    ),
    ...
  ],
),
```

Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Think this is the answer, just also remove `alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,`

Comment: yes problems solved, now I got a list view aligned from left to right.